# New json file added in i18n folder

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

I've added a new `.json` file in `/i18n/en/` directory in `jhipster` generated project. But can't access the value from html page. Am I missing something? (should I need to mention newly created `.json` anywhere?

Comment: is there any constant service there in app.module.js ?

Answer (score 0):

Add it to example.state.js

```
resolve: {
    translatePartialLoader: ['$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function ($translate, $translatePartialLoader) {
        $translatePartialLoader.addPart('example');
        return $translate.refresh();
    }]
}
```